# Query multiple columns of data in Google Sheets and count number occurrences

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to query two columns of data in Google Sheets and count how many times the values occur.

I have made a Google Sheets formula which works but only returns data in the first column.

```
=QUERY(QUERY({D2:D,E2:E}, "select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1"), "select Col1, Col2 order by Col2 desc, Col1 limit 45", 0)
```

How can I query and count data from both columns together?

[image]

**DESIRED RESULT**

2.38 / 2

5.38 / 2

...

I have made a Google Sheet showing an example. This can be copied by going to File-Make a Copy

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S5fE43JPVgUhZFVx-rjowkCy8N6p_ziIhIWe4MweiXQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your formula gives the correct output, you may need to change your comma with semicolon. That way all your data will be grabbed as a single column:

```
=QUERY(QUERY({D2:D;E2:E}, "select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1"), "select Col1, Col2 order by Col2 desc, Col1 limit 45", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=QUERY({D2:D;E2:E},"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY COUNT(Col1) DESC LABEL COUNT(Col1)''")
```

- 

[image]